# Send JWT authentication request using Python's sockets

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I have a webserver which accepts the request for JWT authentication. I'm trying to write a client, using Python's sockets to send the authentication request. However, from server I'm getting 400 - bad request. Password and email are correct, because this is only an example.

**server**

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/auth", methods=["POST"])
def authenticate():
    print(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.json.get("email")
        password = request.json.get("password")
        print(request)
        if not email or not password:
            return 400
        return 200
    else:
        abort(400)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=6000)
```

**client**

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 6000  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1:6000\r\nContent-Type: application/json \r\n")
    s.sendall(b"email=test@test.com&password=p455\r\n\r\n")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data}")
```

Comment: Two things... Why use the *socket* module? You could import *requests* and use that. It will do much more for you. What does the *request* look like on the server side. Have you tried to debug that?

Comment: Because I want to practice sockets. Yes, I tried, but still dont know how to fix this. When I print request at server's site, I see only: `<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth' [POST]>`

Comment: Your server code is invalid. Please show the actual code you're trying to use

Comment: The server's code is fine. I modified it, but the effect is the same

Comment: Your server code (as shown in the question) is not valid. There is no function defined for *abort()*

Comment: Do you know Flask? Its Flask's default, I just forgot to import

Comment: I'm pretty sure that http request is malformed. I think you have at least two issues in it.

Comment: You're trying to send a string pattern that looks rather like a parameter list yet your content type is application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you really want to POST JSON. On the server (Flask) side you could do this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/auth", methods=["POST"])
def authenticate():
    print(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.json:
            email = request.json.get("email")
            password = request.json.get("password")
            if email and password:
                print(f'{email=}')
                print(f'{password=}')
                return Response(status=200)
    return Response(status=400)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=6000)
```

On the client side you need to completely restructure your code as follows:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 6000  # The port used by the server
msg = '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"p455"}'
cl = len(msg)
pr = f'POST /auth HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{HOST}:{PORT}\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: {cl}\r\n\r\n'
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall((pr+msg).encode())
```